# Remove group of empty or nan in pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

In a dataframe, with some empty(NaN) values in some rows - Example below

```
s = pd.DataFrame([[39877380,158232151,20], [39877380,332086469,], [39877380,39877381,14], [39877380,39877383,8], [73516838,6439138,1], [73516838,6500551,], [735571896,203559638,], [735571896,282186552,], [736453090,6126187,], [673117474,12196071,], [673117474,12209800,], [673117474,618058747,6]], columns=['start','end','total'])
```

When I groupby start and end columns

```
s.groupby(['start', 'end']).total.sum()
```

the output I get is

```
start      end
39877380   39877381    14.00
           39877383     8.00
           158232151   20.00
           332086469     nan
73516838   6439138      1.00
           6500551       nan
673117474  12196071      nan
           12209800      nan
           618058747    6.00
735571896  203559638     nan
           282186552     nan
736453090  6126187       nan
```

I want to exclude all the groups of start where all values with end is 'nan' - Expected output -

```
start      end
39877380   39877381    14.00
           39877383     8.00
           158232151   20.00
           332086469     nan
73516838   6439138      1.00
           6500551       nan
673117474  12196071      nan
           12209800      nan
           618058747    6.00
```

I tried with dropna(), but it is removing all the nan values and not nan groups.

I am newbie in python and pandas. Can someone help me in this? thank you

Answer (score 1):

In newer pandas versions is necessary use `min_count=1` for missing values if use `sum`:

```
s1 = s.groupby(['start', 'end']).total.sum(min_count=1)
#oldier pandas version solution
#s1 = s.groupby(['start', 'end']).total.sum()
```

Then is possible filter if at least one non missing value per first level by [`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html) with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and [`GroupBy.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html), filtering is by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
s2 = s1[s1.notna().groupby(level=0).transform('any')]
#oldier pandas version solution
#s2 = s1[s1.notnull().groupby(level=0).transform('any')]
print (s2)
start      end      
39877380   39877381     14.0
           39877383      8.0
           158232151    20.0
           332086469     NaN
73516838   6439138       1.0
           6500551       NaN
673117474  12196071      NaN
           12209800      NaN
           618058747     6.0
Name: total, dtype: float64
```

Or is possible get unique values of first level index values by [`MultiIndex.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.get_level_values.html) and filtering by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
idx = s1.index.get_level_values(0)
s2 = s1.loc[idx[s1.notna()].unique()]
#oldier pandas version solution
#s2 = s1.loc[idx[s1.notnull()].unique()]
print (s2)
start      end      
39877380   39877381     14.0
           39877383      8.0
           158232151    20.0
           332086469     NaN
73516838   6439138       1.0
           6500551       NaN
673117474  12196071      NaN
           12209800      NaN
           618058747     6.0
Name: total, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I tried the both the approach you suggested and I am not able to execute `s1[s1.notna().groupby(level=0).transform('any')]` step and getting error `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'notna'`

Comment: @csvb - It is oldier pandas only, chnage `notna()` to `notnull()` only

Comment: replacing `notna()` with `notnull()` did not work. I am still seeing the last 3 rows but instead of `nan` now they are all `0.00`

Comment: @csvb - So use `s1 = s.groupby(['start', 'end']).total.sum(min_count=1)` instead `s1 = s.groupby(['start', 'end']).total.sum()`

Comment: I am still not able to get the expected result. I followed the step you mentioned. @jezrael

Comment: @csvb - Waht is your pandas version? My solution failed with `s = pd.DataFrame([[39877380,158232151,20], [39877380,332086469,], [39877380,39877381,14], [39877380,39877383,8], [73516838,6439138,1], [73516838,6500551,], [735571896,203559638,], [735571896,282186552,], [736453090,6126187,], [673117474,12196071,], [673117474,12209800,], [673117474,618058747,6]], columns=['start','end','total'])` or only with real data?

Comment: I am trying your suggestion for dataframe example which I shared here. I am executing these using python 3.6.1 and pandas 0.20.1

Comment: @csvb - It is a bit old version of pandas, is possible upgrade?